# What does System.setProperty("rx.unsafe-disable", "True"); do

Tags: android, rx-java

Very occasionally I receive exceptions when using RxJava's `Observable.zip(...).subscribe()`. 
Other people [are having the same problem](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3097) and one [suggestion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3097#issuecomment-225533747) is to do the following:

```
 System.setProperty("rx.unsafe-disable", "True");
```

My question is: what does this specific line of code do in regards to RxJava?

Comment: It disables `Unsafe`-based components due to bugs in some Android devices: [PR 3829](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/3829/files).

Comment: are you asking what the specific command does or generally the System.setProperty()?

Comment: @akarnokd Does this change the behaviour of my RxJava code in any way?

Comment: @matrix This command specifically.

Comment: This command has no effect on the functionality.